# Unexpected PHP Parse Error

Tags: php

I realise that the answer to this question is probably going to be simply obvious, but I am stumped.

I've created a class that uses Jeremy Kendall's Password Validator (https://github.com/jeremykendall/password-validator) called Hash. However, when the class gets called I get:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/james/Projects/REC/htdocs/classes/Hash.class.php on line 24.
```

The code in Hash.class.php that it is having issues with is:

```
private $validationCallback;

public function __construct(){
    $this->validationCallback = function($credential, $passwordHash){
        if (has('md5', $credential) === $passwordHash) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Line 24 is the final '}'. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: MD5? Lordie, do they still use that in the 21st century?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be:

```
private $validationCallback;

public function __construct(){
    $this->validationCallback = function($credential, $passwordHash)
{
    if (has('md5', $credential) === $passwordHash) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}; // Missing semicolon needs to be here
}
```

Please see PHP's [Anonymous Function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) documentation:

> Closures can also be used as the values of variables; PHP automatically converts such expressions into instances of the Closure internal class. Assigning a closure to a variable uses the same syntax as any other assignment, **including the trailing semicolon**:

Answer (score 3):

[Anonymous functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) need a semicolon at the end. Try this:

```
private $validationCallback;

public function __construct(){
$this->validationCallback = function($credential, $passwordHash)
{
if (has('md5', $credential) === $passwordHash) {
    return true;
}
return false;

};
}
```